# How can i open a kotlin class file with double click?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-toolbox

How can I open a Kotlin class file with double click, just like opening a Java class file?

This is what happens when I open a Kotlin class file with double click:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In the toolbar of the project tool window, click on the settings (gear icon) and deselect "Show Members".

Comment: @Slaw, make that an answer so it can be accepted!

Answer (score 0):

You may enable "Open files with single click" option in Project Tree settings (gear icon). It may be also called "Autoscroll to source" if not the latest IDE version is used.